# IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:

Tags: android

I have multiple activities in my app, every activity calls `bindservice` and `unbindservice` to fetch data. In the first activity `bindservice` and `unbindservice` work fine. In the second activity (which reuses the same service) bind service method works fine, but `unbindservice` method gives exception:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:
```

Please help.

Comment: what contexts are you using to bind to the service ?

Comment: Please post the logcat.

Comment: Better discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277673/android-services-error-service-not-registered

Answer (score 10):

NikkyD's question is very good and it helped find the cause of this exception in my case. To anyone out there experiencing the same problem, make sure that your bindService call and unbindService call are done against the same context. Hope it helps.

Comment: yep that was exactly it for me - I had binding done with the App context but accidentally did the unbind with the Activities cxt.

Comment: Also my problem was I used Activity Context to bind and Application to unbind. You must not do that.

Answer (score 5):

Multiple clients can connect to the service at once. However, the system calls your service's onBind() method to retrieve the IBinder only when the first client binds. The system then delivers the same IBinder to any additional clients that bind, without calling onBind() again.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html
Multiple components can bind to the service at once, but when all of them unbind, the service is destroyed.
So,please check if you have kill the service at first time.
May be pass the IBind to every activity much more better.Because it just return only one.

Comment: Make sure you are making only one unbind per service in an Activity. I was making 2 unbinds accidentally and it crashed with this error on the second. Removing the duplicate unbind solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

## Why do we get this error?

Sometimes we get this error when in an Activity `unbindService()` gets called before `bindService()`

[image]

### A common example

is when we bindService in `onCreate()` and unbindService in `onPause()` or `onStop()` of Activity.

#### How to avoid?

**Case 1:** When you want to interact with the service only when the Activity is visible then follow this order.

> bindService() in `onStart()` and unbindService() in `onStop()`

**Case 2:** When you want to interact with service even the Activity is in Background then

> bindService() in `onCreate()` and unbindService() in `onDestroy()`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with an old API. (Android 2.2)
I got this error when I called this method: (from the billing tutorial)

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       try {
           if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
           mHelper = null;
       }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
           Log.d("TMA Billing Android 2.2","Error: "+e.getMessage());
           mHelper = null;
       }

    }
```

As you can see, I surrounded it with Try Catch and now it is working with no problem on Android 2.2.