# Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have a setup that looks something like this:

```
class MyFragment implements SomeEventListener {

    Application mAppContext;    

    boolean mBound;
    boolean mDidCallUnbind;
    MyIBinder mBinder;
    ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mBound = true;
            mBinder = (MyIBinder) service;
            mBinder.getThings();...
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mDidCallUnbind = false;
            mBound = false;
            mBinder = null;
        }
    };

    ...

    @Override
    public void onSomeEvent() {
        mAppContext.bindService(...);
    }

    void unbindService() {
        if (mBound && !mDidCallUnbind) {
            mDidCallUnbind = true;
            mAppContext.unbindService(mConnection);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        unbindService();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

However, I am still seeing the error in the title from time to time: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered` being generated when `unbindService()` is called.  Am I missing something silly, or is there more going on?  I should note that there may be more than one of this same fragment in existence.

*Edit*

Since no one actually seems to be reading the code, let me explain.  `unbindService()` does not call `Context.unbindService(ServiceConnection)` unless the service is bound (`mBound`) **and** it had not previously been called before the `onServiceDisconnected(...)` callback was hit from a possible previous call to `unbindService()`.

That in mind, are there any cases where Android will unbind your service for you such that the service would become unbound but onServiceDisconnected would not be called thus leaving me in a stale state?

Also, I am using my Application context to do the initial binding.  Assume something like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mApplication = getContext().getApplicationContext();
}
```

Comment: If `onSomeEvent()` never happens before `onPause()` then your service is not bound.

Comment: @JustinJasmann clearly.  Did you read my code?

Comment: Yes. You haven't shown where you initialize `mAppContext`, which context are you using?

Comment: @JustinJasmann the application context.  `mAppContext` is of type `Application`.

Comment: @dcow, did you find the cause or the solution to this? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @burakk I did not. We sorta re-architected a bit so it wasn't a problem but to this day I don't know what was up.

Comment: I was having the same issue. This http://stackoverflow.com/a/16713212 answer helped.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I realize this question has already been answered. But I think there is reason to go into why people are making this mistake.

The issue is really with the training docs. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html shows a correct implementation while https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html in the 'ActivityMessenger' shows a Very **INCORRECT** implementation.

In the 'ActivityMessenger' example onStop() could potentially be called before the service has actually been bound.

The reason for this confusion is they are using the bound service boolean to mean different things in different examples. (mainly, was bindService() called OR is the Service actually connected)

In the correct examples where unbind() is done based on the value of the bound boolean, the bound boolean indicates that the **bindService() was called**. Since it's queued up for main thread execution, then unbindService() needs to be called (so queued to be executed), regardless of when (if ever) onServiceConnected() happens.

In other examples, such as the one in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html. The bound indicates that the Services is Actually bound so that you can use it and not get a NullPointerException. Note that in this example, the unbindService() call is still made and the **bound boolean doesn't determine whether to unbind or not**.

Comment: I knew I'd seen it both ways but couldn't remember where the misinformation was coming from...thanks for making the connection.

Comment: So, in short, I should use the boolean bindService() returns instead of depending on onServiceConnected(), right?

Comment: @PNDA Yes, that's what the documentation says now: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#bindService(android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int)

Comment: onServiceConnected is called but the service is not bounded? what the hell

Comment: I've been investigating the same `IllegalArgumentException` issue on my end, and finally found the solution after reading through these suggestions and conversations. In my case, I was using a different `Context` instance in the calls to bind and unbind the service, since I am working with Localization in my app, I was using a "Localized" version of my `Context` to bind, and then my "Main Application" context instance to unbind; which always resulted in the `IllegalArgumentException` to be thrown. 

Answer (score 37):

Use `mIsBound` inside `doBindService()` and `doUnbindService()` instead of in the `ServiceConnection` instance.

```
ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mBinder = (MyIBinder) service;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mBinder = null;
    }
}; 

...

public void doBindService() {
    mIsBound =bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class),
        mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); 
}

public void doUnbindService() {
    if (mIsBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mIsBound = false;
    }
}
```

This is how it's done in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: does not make sense. you are setting mIsBound *before* it is actually bound? I believe bindService is on another thread.

Comment: @likejiujitsu the documentation states for the bindService method:
`If you have successfully bound to the service, true is returned; false is returned if the connection is not made so you will not receive the service object. However, you should still call unbindService(ServiceConnection) to release the connection.`

In other words the connection is made as soon as the method returns, thus after calling this method you MUST unbind the service.

Comment: I can't see the "however" part on the documentation anymore.
Maybe we should not be calling unbind if the bind has returned false

Comment: @Rolfツ Maybe the documentation has changed then. It now states `true if the system is in the process of bringing up a service that your client has permission to bind to; false if the system couldn't find the service or if your client doesn't have permission to bind to it. If this value is true, you should later call unbindService(ServiceConnection) to release the connection.` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#bindService(android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int)

Answer (score 10):

Another possible reason for this exception might be that `unbindService` is called by the wrong `Context`. Because services can be bound not only by Activities, but also by other instances inherited by `Context` (with the exception of BroadcastReceivers), even by other Services, be sure that `unbindService` is called by the context that has bound the `Service` and not by the bound `Service` itself. This would yield directly the above exception "Service not registered".

Answer (score 8):

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered` means that you weren't bound to service when `unbindService()` was called.

So in your case, `onSomeEvent()` was never called before call to `unbindService()` in `onPause()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but please explain how the call to Context.unbindService(ServiceConnection); in my code can be hit.

Comment: I have the exact same issue with my application. Every now and then I get IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: The relevant docs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277673/android-services-error-service-not-registered/16713212#16713212

Comment: What is the solution?

Answer (score 6):

## Reason?

If in your Activity, unbindService() gets called before bindService() then you will get this `IllegalArgumentException`.

**How to avoid it?**
It's simple. You would not need a boolean flag if you bind and unbind service in this order.

> **Solution 1:**
>
> Bind in `onStart()` and unbind in `onStop()`

```
Your Activity {

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        bindService(intent, mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        unbindService(mConnection);
    }

 }
```

> **Solution 2:**
>   Bind in `onCreate()` and unbind in `onDestroy()`

```
 Your Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bindle sis)
    {
        super.onCreate(sis);
        ....
        bindService(intent, mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbindService(mConnection);
    }         

 }
```

### Relevant Link:

Android official documentation [suggests](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Additional_Notes) that
If you need to interact with the service only while your activity is **visible** then go with **Solution1**.
If you want your activity to receive responses even while it is stopped in the **background** then go with **Solution2**.

Comment: Stopping & unbinding the Service is not correlated to Activity lifecycle

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I called bindService using `Activity Context` and trying to unbind it using `ApplicationContext`. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue with my application. Every now and then I get `IllegalArgumentException`. I guess the special case is caused when the service is unbound and the `onPause` is called *before* `onServiceDisconnected`. So I would try `Synchronized` things to ensure correct execution.

Comment: But aren't these all called on the same thread?  Perhaps I was mistaken in thinking that.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ServiceBindManager<T>(val context: Context, clazz: Class<T>) {

    val TAG: String = "ServiceBindManager"

    private val isBound: AtomicBoolean = AtomicBoolean(false)

    private var intent: Intent = Intent(context, clazz)

    private val connection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected: $context")
            isBound.set(true)
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected: $context")
            isBound.set(false)
        }

        override fun onBindingDied(name: ComponentName?) {
            isBound.set(false)
        }

        override fun onNullBinding(name: ComponentName?) {
            isBound.set(false)
        }
    }


     fun bindService() {
        Log.e(TAG, "bindService: $context")
        isBound.set(context.bindService(intent, connection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE))
    }

     fun unbindService() {
        Log.e(TAG, "unbindService: $context")
        if (isBound.get()) {
            isBound.set(false)
            context.unbindService(connection)
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        serviceBindManager = ServiceBindManager(this@MyActivity, MyService::class.java)
}

 override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        serviceBindManager.bindService()
}

 override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        serviceBindManager.unbindService()
}
```