# app crash when updated the google gms service and firebase version (loadapk.java)

Tags: android, firebase

when I updated the google gms service to version 16.0.0 ,google firebase version 16.0.9, my app will crash at app start sometimes, anyone has some problem?

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>   Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf@6dcc201

I try to update the google gms service and `Firebase` to the latest version ,but is some problem ,has anyone can help me ?

**Crash Report**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf@6dcc201
    android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher (LoadedApk.java:1654)
    android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService (ContextImpl.java:1818)
    android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService (ContextWrapper.java:697)
    com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.unbindService (ConnectionTracker.java:25)
    com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf.zzf (zzf.java:41)
    com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.handleMessage (zze.java:45)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:104)
    com.google.android.gms.internal.common.zze.dispatchMessage (zze.java:7)
    android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7529)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
    com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:245)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Comment: Please add the content of your both biuld.gradle files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079909/android-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-service-not-registered